# python script invalid character

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to run scripts using python on a mac osx 10.9.2, and I'm not getting this invalid character problem I'm having.

I have a script with just this line:
print “why does this not work? what non-ascii char?”;

If I run it using python (2.7.5), it gives this error:

```
File "script.2.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file script.2.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

If I change the script to:

```
print(“what invalid char in identifier!?”);
```

and run it with python 3.4.0, I get:

```
File "script.3.py", line 1
    print(“what invalid char in identifier!?”);
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Can someone please help? How do I specify char coding? Thanks.

Comment: Your quotes aren't straight `"` quotes. Are you writing this is TextEdit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have smart quotes!

Perhaps you typed your source code into a word processor, or copied it from a website with bad auto-formatting.  Either way, just replace them with straight quotes (the `"` character).

Python 2 complains that the smart quotes are not part of ASCII.  Python 3 is okay with non-ASCII characters but complains that they aren't the expected kind of quotes.  Either way, the solution is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I did it using textedit. Will start using IDLE at some point down the road as I continue the online tutorial.

Comment: @rockhammer I would recommend sublimetext or another straight programming text editor over IDLE, but any of those will indeed solve your quote problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using quotes that are not equivalent to the quotes used in python to delineate strings --

`" vs “`

```
>>> '“' == '"'
False
```

Replace them and the error will go away.