# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier errors in python

Tags: python, invalid-characters

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier errors in python

In the below picture you can see invalid character in identifier in my project can you help me with this problem?

[image: invalid character in identifier in my projec]

Comment: Your code must have been written in a word processor, since those aren't standard quote characters. Also you have to post text here, not images of code or errors ever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python script invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917329/python-script-invalid-character)

Comment: nope you couldnt help me

Comment: Then you must not be trying very hard to understand your issue, since that clearly explains what's happening.